# Boost read_json is not working with wptree from std::wstring

Tags: c++, json, boost, boost-propertytree

I have a simple code which is not working and I don't really know why... here it's:

```
std::wstring CDbFilterSerializer::DeserializeFromString(const std::wstring& jsonStr)
{
    std::wistringstream ss{ jsonStr };
    boost::property_tree::read_json(ss, m_root);
    return m_root.data();
}
```

The problem here is that after calling **m_root.read_json(...)** the wptre object is empty. The return statement is an example, cause the real code after populating the wptree object, I call m_root.get("MyKey") to start reading values and this throw an exception cause the object is empty.

The json received as parameter is:

```
{
"type":{
      "className":"NumericFilterSerializerHelper: NumericType => unsigned int, DbSerializer => class CDbFilterSerializerByNumericValue",
      "description":""
   },
   "data":{
      "int_number":"45"
   }
}
```

Is there something wrong here?

Comment: @JasonAller let's keep all the boost- tags prefixed consistently. `ptree` is not a thing in software - and if it is, it has nothing to do with `boost-propertytree`. I realize `ptree` exists, but it should be merged with the more frequent [tag:boost-propertytree]

Comment: @sehe did you mean to tag me in that comment, or the author who used the tag?

Comment: @JasonAller Ah, I couldn't see the edit so I surmised it must have been the tags. That's not the case, so sorry to bother you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The assumptions are wrong. `.data()` returns the value at the root node, which is empty (since it's an object). You can print the entire `m_tree` to see:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7acf2909ff6d0e57)**

```
#include <boost/property_tree/json_parser.hpp>
#include <iostream>

struct CDbFilterSerializer {
    std::wstring DeserializeFromString(const std::wstring& jsonStr);

    boost::property_tree::wptree m_root;
};

std::wstring CDbFilterSerializer::DeserializeFromString(const std::wstring& jsonStr)
{
    std::wistringstream ss{ jsonStr };
    read_json(ss, m_root);
    return m_root.data();
}

int main() {
    CDbFilterSerializer obj;
    obj.DeserializeFromString(LR"({
"type":{
      "className":"NumericFilterSerializerHelper: NumericType => unsigned int, DbSerializer => class CDbFilterSerializerByNumericValue",
      "description":""
   },
   "data":{
      "int_number":"45"
   }
})");

    write_json(std::wcout, obj.m_root, true);
}
```

Which prints

```
{
    "type": {
        "className": "NumericFilterSerializerHelper: NumericType => unsigned int, DbSerializer => class CDbFilterSerializerByNumericVa
lue",
        "description": ""
    },
    "data": {
        "int_number": "45"
    }
}
```

As you can see the object is *not* empty. You probably have the path misspelled (we can't tell because `MyKey` is not in your document).

### SIDE NOTE

Do not abuse Property Tree for JSON "support". Instead use a JSON library! Boost JSON exists. Several others are freely available.